# Unity3d : Access the OnClick parameters of Button in a script

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, button, onclick

[image]

I have a button and I have attached another script "`PlaySound`" for this button, which plays audio on button click. As soon as the audio gets completed, I want to stop the animation which I am triggering here in `OnClick` of `Button`. How do I access the `Ellen` gameObject and `0` parameter which I set in the Inspector window (check the picture) in the `PlaySound` script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You're better off writing this as C# code

What you have now functionally looks like this:

```
public class SomeScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public Animator ellen;
    void Start() {
        GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate() {
            ellen.SetTrigger(0);
        });
    }
}
```

Where this script is attached to your button and the Ellen gameobject's `Animator` component is assigned to the `ellen` field.

If you change it like so:

```
public class SomeScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public Animator ellen;
    public float audioDuration;
    void Start() {
        GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate() {
            StartCoroutine(TriggerAnimation());
        });
    }

    IEnumerator TriggerAnimation() {
        ellen.SetTrigger(0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(audioDuration);
        ellen.ResetTrigger(0); //or however you want to return to the idle state
    }
}
```

Now you just need to supply a duration for the audio clip. There may also be a way to query the audio source's [current play status](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-isPlaying.html), but I don't have enough information about your project to be able to hash that code out in a functional way.